# 流すのもなんなので - Translation help

Tags: translation, nuances, particles

I'm currently reading through the 灰と幻想のグリムガル light novel at the moment and have become stuck on this page containing the below sentence.

[I've provided an image for context as I think you'll need it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J96bV.jpg)

The first half of the sentence I need help with is this:

> **流すのもなんなので**、ハルヒロはとりあえず「....親族なの？」と尋ねてみた。

The official English Translation for this book translates it as so:

> It would be awkward to leave that hanging, so Haruhiro offered, “...Maybe they're in the same family?”.

I know it's connected to the topic of the last paragraph, but I can't seem to fully wrap my head around its full meaning and how its deconstructed.

If someone could explain this to me like I'm 5 that would be fantastic.

Thanks,

Archie ♥

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that context,

「流{なが}す」 means 「聞{き}き流す」, which means "***to take no notice and show no reaction***" to what has just been said by the other person.  People tend to 「流す」 what they think to be poor jokes, uninteresting or useless comments, etc.

「なん」 here is  a filler word for an actual word that is ***negative*** in meaning.  In this case, that word would be 「良{よ}くない」, 「悪{わる}い」, etc.

So, 「流すのもなんなので」 would mean something along the lines of:

> "As it would not be too cool to take no notice of (what Yume has just said)"